# converting video format

Tags: android, android-emulator, video-conversion

In android mobile, if we shoot a video, the video will be in 3gp format.  But my application will not accept 3gp video, I want to  convert the 3gp to mp4 or flv or swf.
I need to install the FFMPEG inside my android emulator to convert 3gp to mp4. How it can be done? Please help me if anybody knows.

Regards
Sundar.

Comment: "In android mobile, if we shoot a video, the video will be in 3gp format" -- `MediaRecorder` appears to support MP4 along with 3GP.

Comment: I need to convert the video and upload it to php server..How it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

[user1004789 aka Sundar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004789/user1004789)

```
> "But my application will not accept 3gp video"
> I need to convert the video and upload it to php server..
```

Or you use a [video converter](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=video%20converter&c=apps)
or configure your server, [google is your friend](https://www.google.pt)

http://blog.bounceweb.com/installing-ffmpeg-mencoder-gpac-for-3gp-video-conversion-server-for-centos/
http://documentation.hwdmediashare.co.uk/wiki/Setting_up_your_server_for_hwdVideoShare